# Had trouble linking widget to a queried datasource

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm sure everyone already knows this, but it took me a while to figure out so I thought I would share.

Basically I was trying tell a widget to change color based on the current status of an entry in my model.

But I needed Widget 1 to change for Room 201, Widget 2 to change for Room 202, etc.

Ex:

Room: 201, Status: Available = Widget 1: Green
Room: 202, Status: Booked = Widget 2: Red

I could get the widgets to change color (thanks to borrowing from the code in the [Project List Sample](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/project-list/)), but I was confused how to change their individual datasources to a query. They would basically only show the color corresponding to the currently selected item in the database/table.

So, here is what I did:

Went into my Model, went under Datasources and added a new Datasource.

Ex name: Room201

Then in the Query builder I put in the Field I was trying to narrow by.

ex: Room = :Query

(Room = my field, and I believe the ":Query" is the just name of the query, someone can correct me if I'm wrong)

Then you'll see a box below that window where you can add a binding. So THAT is where I put in my query.

ex: @datasources.Facilities.query.filters.Room._equals = 201

(Note: I had to create a separate Datasource for each room)

Then I went to my widget and chose the queried datasource (Room201) for the datasource.

So Widget 1 = the datasource Room201, Widget 2 = the datasource Room202, etc.

Done.

Hopefully that helps someone!

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, but the way to do that is to ask a question that someone with the same problem is likely to search for in the Question box and put the answer in the Answer box below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer. Do not put answers in the Question box or put “Solved” in the title; neither of those things marks the question as answered in the UI.

Comment: Okay, sorry. Just trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

Posting the author's (Adam Bergeron) solution to the question as an actual Stack Overflow answer:

"
So, here is what I did:

Went into my Model, went under Datasources and added a new Datasource.

Ex name: Room201

Then in the Query builder I put in the Field I was trying to narrow by.

ex: Room = :Query

(Room = my field, and I believe the ":Query" is the just name of the query, someone can correct me if I'm wrong)

Then you'll see a box below that window where you can add a binding. So THAT is where I put in my query.

ex: @datasources.Facilities.query.filters.Room._equals = 201

(Note: I had to create a separate Datasource for each room)

Then I went to my widget and chose the queried datasource (Room201) for the datasource.

So Widget 1 = the datasource Room201, Widget 2 = the datasource Room202, etc.

Done.

Hopefully that helps someone!
"