# Filter table data in Accordion Widget

Tags: google-app-maker

In AppMaker I want to show products in tables and separate the products with the accordion widget based on the assigned product category. So the different accordion details have only a product table of the specific category.

I have two data models with the following field:

- Table 1: Categories

  - Field 1: Id *
  - Field 2: Name
- Table 2: Products

  - Field 1: Id
  - Field 2: Name
  - Field 3: CategoryId *

The Accordion widget is bind to Categories (Names). In the Accordion detail, I add Table widget bounded to Products. How can I 'filter' the data, so only the products of the specific category is showed in the Category detail.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, it sounds like a similar issue I had. I posted the full details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881534/had-trouble-linking-widget-to-a-queried-datasource).

Again if I'm understanding your situation, you'll want to create a new datasource for your model, then enter a query in the query builder to filter a specific category, then point that widget to that new datasource.

Answer (score 0):

If you have relation between Category and Product then potentially you can use binding through relation. Just drop List or Table widget to your accordion details panel and bind it to item relation:

```
@datasource.item.Products
```

In this binding 'item' is your Category and 'Products' is your your relation name.

If number of products is small, then you can use [prefetch](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#prefetch) to load Categories and Products in one request. Otherwise, I would not recommend  using relation prefetching. Also, if you need to show only N products from ALL, you can [take control over list/table rows creation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/widgets#widget_properties)(performance settings).

```
// in list/table row onDataLoad event
if (widget.childIndex < 10) {
  widget.createChildren();
}
```

- [Panel -> Methods -> createChildren()](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#Panel)
- [Control when content loads](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/widgets#control_when_content_loads)